# How to count words from an array of chars in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, char, word-count

I'm having an issue in trying to receive the letters from the array of chars into my wordCount function to count the number of words in each item of an array. I believe I should only manipulate the function but am unclear on how to get the individual letters from the testCases array into the word count function.

After that, I would assume I would use if statements to check whether characters read into wordCount are either letters and when they end to count them as a word.

code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototype
int wordCount (char *userEntry);

int main() {
// Constants
const int MAX_LENGTH = 150;

// Local variables
char testCases[][MAX_LENGTH + 1] = { "0",
    "    1   22    3333    44444 ",
    "     testing    ",
    "a",
    "onetwothree",
    "one two three",
    "    testing    a    11   222  three  4  five  ",
    "a b c d e f" };
int wCount = 0;

// loop through test cases and display number of words in each
for (char *entry : testCases) {
    wCount = wordCount(entry);
    cout << "\nNumber of words in the test case '" << entry << "' is: " 
<< wCount << endl;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
Function Name:  wordCount
This function counts the # of space-delimited words
in a character string, and returns the count to the
caller.
NOTE: A word is defined as one or more alphabetic
characters separated by one or more spaces,
unless it is the only alphabetic character(s).
*/

int wordCount (char *userEntry) {

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings in c++ are null terminated, which means that after their last character there is a `'\0'` character with character code `0x00`. To read each character of a string/character array you just use the index operator `[]`. Strings in C++ like other arrays are indexed from 0 to n-1

here is an example for loop which will read a character of a string into a character variable.

```
void iterate_through_characters(const char* aString) {
    // starting at n=0 check each n and make sure it is shorter than the
    // width of the array
    // and that it's not the null terminating character
    for (int n = 0; (n < MAX_LENGTH + 1) && (aString[n] != '\0'); n++) {
        // take the character out of the index in the string and store it in aCharacter
        char aCharacter = aString[n];
    }
}
```

For your special case you'd also want to keep track whether you are in a word already or not, and only count a new word if you aren't already in a word. The below function implements this.

```
int wordCount(const char* input) {

    // this is true if we're in a word
    bool inWord = false; 

    // the number of words we've seen defaulting to 0, no words
    int result = 0;

    for (int n = 0; (n < MAX_LENGTH + 1) && (aString[n] != '\0'); n++) {
       // if this is a space we're not in a word
       if (aString[n] == ' ') {
           inWord = false; // if we were in a word, we aren't now
       } else if (!inWord) {
           inWord = true; // if we weren't in a word, we are now
           result ++; // increment the number of words we've seen 
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```